# My TABLEAU pie chart´s colors aren´t corresponding to the numbers

Tags: colors, tableau-api, pie-chart

I am stuck in a pie chart that should be very simple...
I have a dataset with 3 columns: 1 - the years, 2 - percentace of yes of each year, 3- percentage of no of each year. All I need to do is a pie with the total average of yes/no percentage of all years.

So I put the yes field selecting average on label, I put the no field selecting average on label, I put measure values (selecting yes and no) on colors. As result I get a pie with the numbers of yes and no being showed at the 2 sides of the chart. These number are correct (42x58).
But the pie´s colors are like it is exactly 50x50. Why isnt it obeying the label?